# Remove Netmiko Automatic Output

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I have a quick question in regards to the Netmiko module (based on the Paramiko module).

I have a for loop that iterates through a bunch of Cisco boxes (around 40)...and once they complete I get the following each time a SSH connection establishes:

***SSH connection established to ip address:22***

***Interactive SSH session established***

This isn't in my print statements or anything, it's obviously hard coded within ConnectionHandler (which I use to make the SSH connections).

This output really makes my output muddled and full of 40 extra lines I do not need.  Is there any way I can get these removed from the output?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer out through reddit.

Add the key 'verbose': False to your network device dictionary. More information on the Netmiko Standard Tutorial page